# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, so that $f(x)=\lfloor{2\lceil{\frac x2}\rceil}+\frac 12 \rfloor$. How do I find $f([-4,-2])$?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

By using logic I can see that the answer is $\{-4,-2\}$, but what is the correct way to format the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Consider what happens when $x\in (2n,2n+2]$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then 
$\frac{x}{2}\in (n,n+1]$ and
$$f(x)=\lfloor 2\lceil\frac{x}{2}\rceil+\frac{1}{2} \rfloor=
\lfloor 2(n+1)+\frac{1}{2} \rfloor=2n+2\implies f((2n,2n+2])=\{2n+2\}.
$$
What is $f([-4,-2])=f(-4)\cup f((-4,-2])$?

Comment: @user391135 Any further doubt?

Comment: I understand this, but I'm actually curious if there's a particular scheme to follow when solving floor and ceiling functions? Like when I want to write the solution on paper as clearly as possible.

Comment: @user391135 I have no general method.The trick is to restrict the variable in some interval. Usually functions with floor and ceiling are piecewise constant.

Comment: @user391135 In your example the function is costant on the intervals of the form $(2n,2n+2]$.First find these intervals (in some way), then show that the function is constant there .

Comment: Okay, but would it also be okay to find $f(-4)=-4$ and $f(-2)=-2$, then see that the only integer between them is $-3$, and show that there is no solution for $f^{-1}(-3)$?

Comment: @user391135 No. How can you be sure that in between something bad happens. Say $f$ attains the value $1$.